# I have problems with anaconda and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda, anaconda3

Actually i just started software (2 days maybe) and i'm using udemy, sorbil education site etc. Now i downloaded anaconda 3 but this app is out of date. App warn me about "You can update now 2.5.1 version" but i am not updating. ı dont know why?

(i have 3.12.1 version python)

[LOOK= I click yes but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n069n.png)

[Jupyter notebook does not work via cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jku28.png)

[The box I marked at the bottom left constantly moves, but the notebook does not turn on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYyMx.png)

[did you see that? I start jupyter notebook from the start menu. And when I open it from here, the code does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSbHc.png)

[PyCharm is working btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chyrx.png)

At one point, Jupyter notebook was opened via cmd and the codes were working. But after a while it doesn't work. I deleted everything and reinstalled it, but the problem is still not solved. WATCHA GONNA DO I?

Comment: You need to activate the anaconda virtual env at the prompt (eg. conda activate).  In Jupyter, you need to execute the code, so, for example, hit the play button or shift enter to execute the cell (ie print hello world).  Check out https://freelearning.anaconda.cloud/get-started-with-anaconda.  Anaconda and jupyter are worth the effort :)

Comment: Actually i tried many things but i couldnt fix. And I formatted my computer XDD Its working right now. BTW thx for link and your help bro. Good Days.